# Out of line definition of template function vs in class

Tags: c++, templates, code-readability

I wondered if there was any advantages of declaring templates function out of line vs in the class.

I'm trying to get a clear understanding of the pros and cons of the two syntax.

Here's an example:

Out of line:

```
template<typename T>
struct MyType {
    template<typename... Args>
    void test(Args...) const;
};

template<typename T>
template<typename... Args>
void MyType<T>::test(Args... args) const {
    // do things
}
```

Vs in class:

```
template<typename T>
struct MyType {
    template<typename... Args>
    void test(Args... args) const {
        // do things
    }
};
```

Are there language features that are easier to use with the first or second version? Does the first version would get in the way when using default template arguments or enable_if? I would like to see comparisons of how those two cases are playing with different language features like sfinae, and maybe potential future features (modules?).

Taking compiler specific behavior into account can be interesting too. I think MSVC needs `inline` in some places with the first code snippet, but I'm not sure.

EDIT: I know there is no difference on how these features works, that this is mostly a matter of taste. I want to see how both syntaxes plays with different techniques, and the advantage of one over the other. I see mostly answers that favors one over another, but I really want to get both sides. A more objective answer would be better.

Comment: Those implementations have different effects. The latter function is implicitly declared `inline`, the former isn't. So that would be a difference, anyway, and having the function declared `inline` is certainly an advantage, if you care about a happy linker.

Comment: I don't think there is any difference in functionality, but the out of line one puts the definition somewhere else, clearing up the class definition and so finding functions becomes easier.

Comment: @IInspectable templates aren't subject to the one-definition rule, so `inline` has no effect here.

Comment: I find it easier to read a summary of what `MyType` does when the functions are defined out of line.  It is harder to write, but I prioritize readability over writability: http://howardhinnant.github.io/coding_guidelines.html

Comment: _advantages of declaring templates function out of line vs in the class_ <- do you mean _defining_?

Comment: Yes I meant defining. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: Except `in-class` being `inline` by default, there is no difference. It is opinion based, just like variable naming.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Are there language features that are easier to use with the first or second version?

Quite trivial a case, but it's worth to be mentioned: *specializations*.

As an example, you can do this with out-of-line definition:

```
template<typename T>
struct MyType {
    template<typename... Args>
    void test(Args...) const;

    // Some other functions...
};

template<typename T>
template<typename... Args>
void MyType<T>::test(Args... args) const {
    // do things
}

// Out-of-line definition for all the other functions...

template<>
template<typename... Args>
void MyType<int>::test(Args... args) const {
    // do slightly different things in test
    // and in test only for MyType<int>
}
```

If you want to do the same with in-class definitions only, you have to duplicate the code for all the other functions of `MyType` (supposing `test` is the only function you want to specialize, of course).
As an example:

```
template<>
struct MyType<int> {
    template<typename... Args>
    void test(Args...) const {
        // Specialized function
    }

    // Copy-and-paste of all the other functions...
};
```

Of course, you can still mix in-class and out-of-line definitions to do that and you have the same amount of code of the full out-of-line version.
Anyway I assumed you are oriented towards full in-class and full out-of-line solutions, thus mixed ones are not viable.

---

Another thing that you can do with out-of-line class definitions and you cannot do with in-class definitions at all is function template specializations.
Of course, you can put the primary definition in-class, but all the specializations must be put out-of-line.

In this case, the answer to the above mentioned question is: *there exist even features of the language that you cannot use with one of the version*.

As an example, consider the following code:

```
struct S {
    template<typename>
    void f();
};

template<>
void S::f<int>() {}

int main() {
    S s;
    s.f<int>();
}
```

Suppose the designer of the class wants to provide an implementation for `f` only for a few specific types.
He simply can't do that with in-class definitions.

---

Finally, out-of-line definitions help to break circular dependencies.
This has been already mentioned in [most of](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40464037/4987285) [the other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40381955/4987285) and it doesn't worth it to give another example.

Comment: Damn! I would so much like to accept multiple answers. They almost all bring good points!

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Well, I tried to give you an idea of the fact that some things cannot be done at all with one of the solutions. All the other cases had already been explored by the other answers and I didn't mention them a second time. ;-)

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Added a mention about circular dependencies for completeness. No examples for you already have enough of them in the other answers. ;-)

Comment: I'm less sure about the circular dependency argument. Look at this example I left in another comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d420ae7ba2ab9b08 or maybe your circular dependency example is about something else?

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I understand that you can work around it with intermediate classes and maybe in some other ways. That's also why I added one more answer with different motivations and examples. I said only that out-of-line definitions help to break dependencies, not that they are the only way to do that. On the other side, specializations simply cannot be put in-class and that's all. Good question anyway, really interesting.

Answer (score 23):

There is no difference between the two versions regarding default template arguments, SFINAE or `std::enable_if` as overload resolution and substitution of template arguments work the same way for both of them. I also don't see any reason why there should be a difference with modules, as they don't change the fact that the compiler needs to see the full definition of the member functions anyway.

#### Readability

One major advantage of the out-of-line version is readability. You can just declare and document the member functions and even move the definitions to a separate file that is included in the end. This makes it so that the reader of your class template doesn't have to skip over a potentially large number of implementation details and can just read the summary.

For your particular example you could have the definitions

```
template<typename T>
template<typename... Args>
void MyType<T>::test(Args... args) const {
    // do things
}
```

in a file called `MyType_impl.h` and then have the file `MyType.h` contain just the declaration

```
template<typename T>
struct MyType {
   template<typename... Args>
   void test(Args...) const;
};

#include "MyType_impl.h"
```

If `MyType.h` contains enough documentation of the functions of `MyType` most of the time users of that class don't need to look into the definitions in `MyType_impl.h`.

#### Expressiveness

But it is not just increased readibility that differentiates out-of-line and in-class definitions. While every in-class definition can easily be moved to an out-of-line definition, the converse isn't true. I.e. out-of-line definitions are more expressive that in-class definitions. This happens when you have tightly coupled classes that rely on the functionality of each other so that a forward declaration doesn't suffice.

One such case is e.g. the command pattern if you want it to support chaining of commands **and** have it support user defined-functions and functors without them having to inherit from some base class. So such a `Command` is essentially an "improved" version of `std::function`.

This means that the `Command` class needs some form of type erasure which I'll omit here, but I can add it if someone really would like me to include it.

```
template <typename T, typename R> // T is the input type, R is the return type
class Command {
public:
    template <typename U>
    Command(U const&); // type erasing constructor, SFINAE omitted here

    Command(Command<T, R> const&) // copy constructor that makes a deep copy of the unique_ptr

    template <typename U>
    Command<T, U> then(Command<R, U> next); // chaining two commands

    R operator()(T const&); // function call operator to execute command

private:
    class concept_t; // abstract type erasure class, omitted
    template <typename U>
    class model_t : public concept_t; // concrete type erasure class for type U, omitted

    std::unique_ptr<concept_t> _impl;
};
```

So how would you implement `.then`? The easiest way is to have a helper class that stores the original `Command` and the `Command` to execute after that and just calls both of their call operators in sequence:

```
template <typename T, typename R, typename U>
class CommandThenHelper {
public:
    CommandThenHelper(Command<T,R>, Command<R,U>);
    U operator() (T const& val) {
        return _snd(_fst(val));
    }
private:
    Command<T, R> _fst;
    Command<R, U> _snd;
};
```

Note that Command cannot be an incomplete type at the point of this definition, as the compiler needs to know that `Command<T,R>` and `Command<R, U>` implement a call operator as well as their size, so a forward declaration is not sufficient here. Even if you were to store the member commands by pointer, for the definition of `operator()` you absolutely need the full declaration of `Command`.

With this helper we can implement `Command<T,R>::then`:

```
template <typename T, R>
template <typename U>
Command<T, U> Command<T,R>::then(Command<R, U> next) {
    // this will implicitly invoke the type erasure constructor of Command<T, U>
    return CommandNextHelper<T, R, U>(*this, next);
}
```

Again, note that this doesn't work if `CommandNextHelper` is only forward declared because the compiler needs to know the declaration of the constructor for `CommandNextHelper`. Since we already know that the class declaration of `Command` has to come before the declaration of `CommandNextHelper`, this means you simply cannot define the `.then` function in-class. The definition of it has to come after the declaration of `CommandNextHelper`.

I know that this is not a simple example, but I couldn't think of a simpler one because that issue mostly comes up when you absolutely have to define some operator as a class member. This applies mostly to `operator()` and `operator[]` in expession templates since these operators cannot be defined as non-members.

#### Conclusion

So to conclude: It is mostly a matter of taste which one you prefer, as there isn't much of a difference between the two. Only if you have circular dependencies among classes you can't use in-class defintion for all of the member functions. I personally prefer out-of-line definitions anyway, since the trick to outsource the function declarations can also help with documentation generating tools such as doxygen, which will then only create documentation for the actual class and not for additional helpers that are defined and declared in another file.

---

### Edit

If I understand your edit to the original question correctly, you'd like to see how general SFINAE, `std::enable_if` and default template parameters looks like for both of the variants. The declarations look exactly the same, only for the definitions you have to drop default parameters if there are any.

1. Default template parameters

   ```
   template <typename T = int>
   class A {
       template <typename U = void*>
       void someFunction(U val) {
           // do something
       }
   };
   ```

   vs

   ```
   template <typename T = int>
   class A {
       template <typename U = void*>
       void someFunction(U val);
   }; 

   template <typename T>
   template <typename U>
   void A<T>::someFunction(U val) {
       // do something
   }
   ```
2. `enable_if` in default template parameter

   ```
   template <typename T>
   class A {
       template <typename U, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<U, T>::value>>
       bool someFunction(U const& val) {
           // do some stuff here
       }
   };
   ```

   vs

   ```
   template <typename T>
   class A {
       template <typename U, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<U, T>::value>>
       bool someFunction(U const& val);
   };

   template <typename T>
   template <typename U, typename> // note the missing default here
   bool A<T>::someFunction(U const& val) {
       // do some stuff here
   }
   ```
3. `enable_if` as non-type template parameter

   ```
   template <typename T>
   class A {
       template <typename U, std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<U, T>::value, int> = 0>
       bool someFunction(U const& val) {
           // do some stuff here
       }
   };
   ```

   vs

   ```
   template <typename T>
   class A {
       template <typename U, std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<U, T>::value, int> = 0>
       bool someFunction(U const& val);
   };

   template <typename T>
   template <typename U, std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<U, T>::value, int>> 
   bool A<T>::someFunction(U const& val) {
       // do some stuff here
   }
   ```

   Again, it is just missing the default parameter 0.
4. SFINAE in return type

   ```
   template <typename T>
   class A {
       template <typename U>
       decltype(foo(std::declval<U>())) someFunction(U val) {
           // do something
       }

       template <typename U>
       decltype(bar(std::declval<U>())) someFunction(U val) {
           // do something else
       }
   };
   ```

   vs

   ```
   template <typename T>
   class A {
       template <typename U>
       decltype(foo(std::declval<U>())) someFunction(U val);

       template <typename U>
       decltype(bar(std::declval<U>())) someFunction(U val);
   };

   template <typename T>
   template <typename U>
   decltype(foo(std::declval<U>())) A<T>::someFunction(U val) {
       // do something
   }

   template <typename T>
   template <typename U>
   decltype(bar(std::declval<U>())) A<T>::someFunction(U val) {
       // do something else
   }
   ```

   This time, since there are no default parameters, both declaration and definition actually look the same.

Comment: This is actually pretty good. Every point a explained very well. But again, it mostly favors one syntax over the other. I made an edit to the title of my question, I hope it's clearer by now.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot It favors the one syntax over the other because there just is nothing you can do with in-class definitions that you can't do with out-of-line definitions. The only very minor disadvantage of out-of-line definitions is that the compiler has to do slightly more work: It needs to parse more tokens and it has to ensure that the out-of-line definition matches the declaration in the class. But this shouldn't be noticable unless you include the file several thousand times across your project. And even that disadvantage will disappear with modules.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I added some examples showing how SFINAE with and without the different uses of `std::enable_if` look like and how you pass default parameters. Is that what you wanted to see?

Comment: Thanks, with that it's much more complete.

Comment: I would accept your answer, but the main reason you gave to me is about complete types and circular dependency is flawed. Look at this implementation of your command, without any out of class function definition: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d420ae7ba2ab9b08. Hell, I can even invert the definitions: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e79cfc7d69b6c8a2

Answer (score 13):

Separating the declaration from the implementation allows you to do this:

```
// file bar.h
// headers required by declaration
#include "foo.h"

// template declaration
template<class T> void bar(foo);

// headers required by the definition
#include "baz.h"

// template definition
template<class T> void bar(foo) {
    baz();
    // ...
}
```

Now, what would make this useful? Well, the header `baz.h` may now include `bar.h` and depend on `bar` and other declarations, even though the implementation of `bar` depends on `baz.h`.

If the function template was defined inline, it would have to include `baz.h` before declaring `bar`, and if `baz.h` depends on `bar`, then you'd have a circular dependency.

---

Besides resolving circular dependencies, defining functions (whether template or not) out-of-line, leaves the declarations in a form that works effectively as a table of contents, which is easier for programmers to read than declarations sprinkled across a header full of definitions. This advantage diminishes when you use specialized programming tools that provide a structured overview of the header.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to always merge them - but you can't do that if they are codependent. For regular code you usually put the code in a .cpp file, but for templates that whole concept doesn't really apply (and makes for repeated function prototypes). Example:

```
template <typename T>
struct A {
    B<T>* b;
    void f() { b->Check<T>(); }
};

template <typename T>
struct B {
    A<T>* a;
    void g() { a->f(); }
};
```

Of course this is a contrived example but replace the functions with something else. These two classes require each other to be defined before they can be used. If you use a forward declaration of the template class, you still cannot include the function implementation for one of them. That's a great reason to put them out of line, which 100% fixes this every time.

One alternative is to make one of these an inner class of the other. The inner class can reach out into the outer class beyond its own definition point for functions so the problem is kind of hidden, which is usable in most cases when you have these codependent classes.

Comment: "for templates that whole concept doesn't really" Yes it does. I've seen a lot of code defining function of templates out of the class and I've got a lot of code that implement templates in a cpp file with explicit instantiation.

Comment: For non-template code you mostly need the class definition for users to have in a header, and the implementation in some compileable unit, so the split makes sense. For template code, both need to be in a header, so that argument drops. Doesn't mean people won't do it anyway...